# Reverting previous version after deployed to prod

Tags: git, production-environment

I have done with building an application and deployed successfully to a prod environment.I found the application faces issue and want to revert back to previous version.
  In Prod environment however we will not include git and we may only have jar file of that applications and its dependency tools(like to run an java web application which needs tomcat i need to install it there)

Comment: How do you deploy your Git repository to your production environment? Do you use an automation server like TeamCity or Jenkins? Do you deploy by directly copying files? Are you using `git push`?

Comment: yes using jenkins and it will move automatically.Using git push whenever changes happening @ObsidianAge

Answer (score 0):

> In Prod environment however we will not include git and we may only have jar file of that applications and its dependency tools

Then simply repeat your build and deployment process you used to deploy your jar in the first place: by replacing it, you will mirror the source code revert you just did.